# Breaking up existing rails application into UI and API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, user-interface, ruby-on-rails-4

We have an already working rails application but the UI and API is built into 1 application. The problem we are having is that when anything happens to the app for example if it goes down, it affects API and GUI. 3rd party systems can't communicate with the API. We are trying to prevent this. These are my options so far:

option 1: deploy the same application to 2 different ports using puma and unicorn

option 2: have 2 different repos for API and GUI and deploy them separately on the same server

Is there a better way where we can have 1 repository hosting both API and GUI and when GUI goes down, API isn't affected?

Comment: Why do you want to deploy both to the same server? Why are both apps in the same repo?

Comment: It's going to the same server because of the database. Since both UI and API interact with the same database, we can't move the API to another server. Currently, only one app controls both API and GUI. We are trying to separate them but they would interact with the same db

Comment: You can host the app on multiple servers and still have them all connect to the same database.

Comment: But that means I would have to duplicate libraries that both the API and GUI use right? or you mean keep the same app and just host on 2 separate servers like option 1 but on 2 different servers

Comment: A lot of apps use a specific subdomain api.example.com and set this up on a separate server connecting to the same DB. This is probably only a good if the nature of the 'downtime' is really a client/view issue. If there is a problem in your models or controller logic it would probably affect the API also right?

Comment: Downtime has usually been related to delayed jobs not starting during deployment. Do you know anyway you can have api in the same app but deploy it separately?

Comment: Thanks I figured it out. Keep the same codebase and deploy unto 1 server that will serve as the API and one server that will serve as the GUI and a 3rd server being the mysql server

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I figured it out. Keep the same codebase and deploy unto 1 server that will serve as the API and one server that will serve as the GUI and a 3rd server being the mysql server